# How to update the UI when the value of the array changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am displaying the name of each skid by iterating the skidList array.
 I have also provided a button "copy" which calls insertSkid when clicked and "delete" which calls deleteSkid.
  In insertSkid I am updating the skidList array. 
 However, the Modal.Body doesn't update the skid names on changes to the skidList array. 
Here's my code.

```
   const CreateNewTab = () => {
             const [skidList, setSkidList] = useState([]);
                 let newSkid = {};
                 newSkid[name] = "PEN";
                 let newSkidList = [];
                 newSkidList.push(newSkid);
                 setSkidList(newSkidList);
    
            const insertSkid = skid => {
                let newSkidList = skidList;
                newSkidList.push(skid);
                setSkidList(newSkidList);
                console.log("Added New Skid" + skidList.length);
            };
    
            const deleteSkid = (index) => { setSkidList([...skidList.splice(index, 1)]); }

            return (
               <Modal
                backdrop="static"
                show={true}
                centered
                dialogClassName={"createnewskid-modal"}
              >
                <Modal.Body>
                                  {skidList.flatMap((skid, index) => (
                                      <div>
                                          {skid[name]}
                                          <Button onClick={insertSkid.bind(this,skid)}>copy</Button>
<Button onClick={()=> deleteSkid(index)}>delete</Button>
                                          <Divider />
                                      </div>
                    ))}
                </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
              )
          }
```

Comment: `setSkidList([...newSkidList]);`

Comment: This setSkidList(newSkidList) will cause multiples state updates, move this block to useEffect block

Comment: Could you please provide the link to learn more about this change? However, setSkidList([...newSkidList]);  worked.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code your presenting. As previously stated, the useEffect() hook would be useful here to handle the initialization of the skid array:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    let newSkid = {name: "PEN"};
    setSkidList([...skidList, newSkid])
},[]) 
// The empty array second param tells the component to only execute the above code once on mount
```

Note: The spread operator (...) is used here to generate a new list based on skidList to which we are appending newSkid.

Next, you should use the same method just described to update your list in the insertSkid function:

```
const insertSkid = (skid) =>{
    setSkidList([...skidList, skid])
}
```

Finally, I would suggest instead of binding you function, use a anonymous function inside the onclick prop:

```
onClick = {() => insertSkid(skid)}
```

Comment: For removing skid from skidList array. I am using 
const removeSkid = (index) => {
           setSkidList([...skidList.splice(index, 1)]);
} Is this correct way to remove skid from array?

Comment: The most important thing to remember is to not alter the array returned by useState. It should remain immutable (unchanging). Instead you should always replace the array with a new array by making a call to setSkidList(). So to answer your question, slice alters the skidList array itself which breaks the first rule of immutability. So you will need to create a new array and slice that. (e.g. let newList = [...skidList];  setSkidList(newList.splice(index, 1))). Hopefully that all makes sense, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to setSkidList(newSkidList), do it inside useEffect.

```
    const CreateNewTab = () => {
       const [skidList, setSkidList] = useState([]);
    
       useEffect(()=> {
        let newSkid = {};
        newSkid[name] = "PEN";
        setSkidList([newSkid]);
       }, [])
                    
         //...
    }
```

Call setSkidList out of the useEffect block will cause multiple state updates

Answer (score 0):

It because an array is available by link, and for React `skidList` after `push` was not change. Try:

```js
const insertSkid = useCallback((skid) => {
  setSkidList([...skidList, skird]);
}, [skidList]);
```

Comment: Does setSkidList([...skidList, skird]); push skird to skidList?

Comment: What is ...skidList ?

Comment: `[...skidList, skird]` is a ES6 syntax returns a new array with items from `skidList` + `skird` item. More about spread operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useEffect` for inital data load, and for update you can use `prev` to get last state value and update yours and do the return, its not needed you need to add more variable assignment.

```js
 const CreateNewTab = () => {
      const [skidList, setSkidList] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const newSkid = {[name] : "PEN"};
          setSkidList([newSkid]);
    }, [])
    const insertSkid = skid => {
        setSkidList(prev => [...prev, skid]);
    };
    return (
      <div>
          {skidList.flatMap((skid, index) => (
              <div>
                  {skid[name]}
                  <button onClick={insertSkid.bind(this,skid)}>copy</button>
                  <hr />
              </div>
            ))}
        </div>
      )
  }
```